# Can I use client_credentials flow with user access_token to impersonate a User?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, microservices, amazon-cognito

The problem I got is about token sharing between multi backend services and user impersonation
Here is the basic setup of my services

**Web service A** (I owned) => User can login with username + password => I choose to use A**WS Cognito** for verify user identity and Cognito would return a JWT access_token with username in claims. I split **Authentication** and **Authorization**. Cognito just in charge on Authentication part and I got an other service to deal with Authorization.

**The Authorization service**: pass in username (extracted from access_token) and the resource. The service would just return grant or deny

**backend service B** (I owned) => The web **service A** will need to send API request to **service B** however I want ZERO trust to service B, therefore I would not using the same user access token in service B.

**backend service C** (I owned) => The backend **service B** will send API request to **service C**

I have to use AWS Cognito for all token generation etc... and Cognito does not support token exchange grant type.

The problem I got is about token sharing between multi backend services.
Here is the basic setup of my services

**Web service A** (I owned) => User can login with username + password => I choose to use A**WS Cognito** for verify user identity and Cognito would return a JWT access_token with username in claims. I split **Authentication** and **Authorization**. Cognito just in charge on Authentication part and I got an other service to deal with Authorization.

**The Authorization service**: pass in username (extracted from access_token) and the resource. The service would just return grant or deny

**backend service B** (I owned) => The web **service A** will need to send API request to **service B** however I want ZERO trust to service B, therefore I would not using the same user access token in service B.

**backend service C** (I owned) => The backend **service B** will send API request to **service C**

I have to use AWS Cognito for all token generation etc... and Cognito does not support token exchange grant type.

---

My idea: using client_credential flow + user's access_token.

When **service A** got user's access_token it will verify the permission to access **service B** with **Authorization service**. Then it will send an token creation request to Cognito using client_credentials flow with **service B**'s **client_id** and **client_secret**. The machine access_token returned from client_credentials flow would lost **user context**, therefore I also put user's access_token in the request header. So when request lands to **service B**, B will verify the machine access_token and the user's access_token. Then extract username from user's access_token and verify the permission with **Authorization service**

The same logic will be used in the communication between service B to service C

**service B** will use **service C**'s client_id + client_secret to get a machine access_token and pass user's access_token to service C. service C would verify machine access_token and user's access_token then verify user's permission to service C with **Authorization service**

Not sure this idea would work?

Answer (score 0):

A better and simpler option here, since you own all services, is to use scopes, combined with token forwarding. Something like this, though name the scopes after areas of your business data:

- Service A requires tokens with scope A
- Service B requires tokens with scope B
- Service C requires tokens with scope C
- Client is issued an access token with scopes A, B and C

Service A can forward the user JWT access token to Service B - and so on. Each service verifies the JWT's digital signature and also checks for its own required scopes.

This gives you a zero trust architecture where the user identity flows in a verifiable and auditable way. The client credentials flow will not achieve that. Impersonation solutions are used when multiple users are involved, eg an administrator logging in as a customer, when troubleshooting a technical issue.

**SCOPE USAGE**

A, B and C typically represent high level business areas. Eg assigning a client scopes of `orders`, `delivery` and `billing` might be one example, where the client only directly interacts with an Orders API. As long as you keep scopes high level this can be easy to reason about in the client.

Token exchange doesn't elevate scopes by the way. Instead it is typically used to reduce scopes before forwarding the access token to a less trusted API.

The way to change scopes is to get a new access token of course, via a client credentials flow. Typically this should be used to operate on non-user resources, where the user identity is not needed, and there are thus no potential conflicts with user consent.

**CLAIMS USAGE**

Another option might be to use the same `orders` scope across all 3 business areas, while also issuing custom claims to the access token for a particular client. These could give you finer grained control over which delivery and billing options are allowed. The payload for an example access token is shown here:

```json
{
  "sub": "abc123",
  "exp": 1611674155,
  "iss": "https://login.example.com",
  "aud": "api.example.com",
  "scope": "orders",
  "delivery_type": "online",
  "billing_level": 3
}
```

Your API authorization can then trust the claims and restrict access to resources based on those received. This would typically restrict resources to those for the user in the token, but can restrict access however you would like. By locking down the token you can also reduce concerns about forwarding it.

**SUMMARY**

The above techniques are your OAuth toolbox for APIs and you can choose where to apply each of them. The authorization server should give you full control over token issuing, within OAuth guidelines. There should be capabilities to include claims from your business data at the time of token issuance, or to use token exchange later.

You need to choose an authorization server that supports this type of behaviour though, since not all of them do. Out of interest [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/api-authorization-design/) of mine further explores the use of custom claims with Cognito issued access tokens. The intent is to show that suboptimal API techniques are required when the authorization server lacks support.

Comment: Right, seems this model more like re-use same token... and issues of using scope is say Svr A is public facing... and B and C are just internal usage, therefore client should never know any scopes of B and C.

Comment: See the update to my answer, on the options available to you. Usually if you keep the scopes design high level and well named, and avoid using too many of them, this works well in clients.

Comment: Thank you for your update. my concern on using the scope still about if in future I change the service A as a public backend API (no web interface). Customer can create their own app to "place order" on service A. Unless document says "place "order" needs additional scopes "delivery" and "billing". User wold have no idea about the other scopes and they can made mistake as well. ie pass "order" scope only. As Cognito does not have token exchange flow, we cannot really reduce the scope.

Comment: Here is another example when we cannot actually reduce the scope. if Svr B go rogue and we give SvrB a token with "orders" "delivery" and "billing" scope in it. Would that mean SvrB can place order or list "billing" info with that token?

Comment: Have a look at my updated notes on claims, which are typically used to meet the more intricate authorization requirements. This stuff doesn't have good support in AWS Cognito though, so you may want to consider an authorization server with better support.